# How to build a 32bit static binary with Rust?

Tags: rust, rustup

Using [*Creating a basic webservice in Rust*](http://hermanradtke.com/2016/05/16/creating-a-basic-webservice-in-rust.html) and [*Taking Rust everywhere with rustup*](http://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/05/13/rustup.html) as documentation, I have managed to successfully compile a 64 bit static binary with Rust:

```
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

But I can't seem to find out how to build a 32bit static binary.

I did find a `i686-unknown-linux-musl` target when running `rustc --print target-list`, only to find out it is not available when running `rustup target list`.

Am I missing something something or it is not possible yet?

Comment: Is i686-unknown-linux-gnu working ?

Comment: As far as I know, it will not statically link libc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The std binaries for `i686-unknown-linux-musl` is only available on [Rust 1.10](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#misc) or newer. You can create a static binary for `i686` with the following commands:

```
$ rustup default stable # stable must at least 1.10
$ rustup target add i686-unknown-linux-musl
$ cargo build --target i686-unknown-linux-musl
```

The generated binaries can be found on `target/i686-unknown-linux-musl/debug/` or `target/i686-unknown-linux-musl/release/`.

We can check that the generated binary is static linked with `ldd`:

```
$ ldd target/i686-unknown-linux-musl/debug/main
not a dynamic executable
```

Comment: I did try it (with rust 1.10 as stable), but it created a dynamically linked binary. Am I missing something ? The compilation was OK, but when I ran ldd on it I saw it was dynamically linked.

Comment: @AndreiOprisan Updated the answer.

Comment: For a freshly generated project it works as you said, for a project with more dependencies it links dynamically. Should I paste the toml file ?

Comment: Should I paste the toml file? Yes, please.

Comment: Here is a minimal project which has the issue: https://github.com/aoprisan/static-rust . I will try to remove them one by one to find the culprit.